# Prevent specific user to view some widget in dashboard

Tags: thingsboard

I'm new to thingsboard.

I've created dashboards than content data visualization and input to change Server attributes, but I want to hide or prevent public users and some users from viewing some widget, i.e input widgets.

is it possible to do this? and how?

Thank you in advance